# Assembly + C - Sorting Structures

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm working on a project that uses x86 Assembly (NASM) and C together. There's a subroutine written in Assembly that uses indexed addressing modes to figure out if a certain year (int) is lesser or greater than another, then returns -1, 1, or 0 depending on the outcome. It appears that if I input more than about 4 or 5 records, it doesn't sort properly. I've spent a few hours running it through gdb and figured out that on the last iteration of incrementing j for the first time (before i is incremented), it runs the swap even though it shouldn't, but I'm not sure how to fix it just yet. Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

---C code---

Comment: Why not pass function args to `cmpbook`, instead of using two global variables?  That's really ugly (and a bit slower).  Related: this comment is bogus: `mov     esi, [book1]  ; store the pointers to each book`.  That's a load instruction (memory source, not memory dest).

Comment: `uses indexed addressing modes to figure out if a certain year (int) is lesser or greater than another`.  Another totally bogus description.  I was really curious what kind of lookup table you'd invented for comparing integers with address math, *instead of* just using `cmp`, but it turns out you are just using a `[reg + displacement]` addressing mode to access struct fields.

Comment: You're missing a `ret` at the end of your asm function.

Comment: Some of this was set up for us and dictated as far as what we can and can't do. The global variable thing is part of that. We haven't learned how to pass arguments like that between Assembly and C.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. It was because I was setting min = i in the wrong spot. It should be like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < numBooks - 1; i++) {
          /*** WAS HERE ***/
          for (j = i + 1; j < numBooks; j++) {

            /*** SHOULD BE HERE ***/
            min = i;

            /* Copy pointers to the two books to be compared into the
            * global variables book1 and book2 for bookcmp() to see
            */
            book1 = &books[i];
            book2 = &books[j];

            cmpResult = bookcmp();
            /* bookcmp returns result in register EAX--above saves
            * it into cmpResult */

            /* book2 comes before book1, in other
            words, book1 is greater - value stored in
            eax will in this case be 1 */
            if (cmpResult == 1) {
              min = j;
            }

            if (min != i) {
              tempBook = books[i];
              books[i] = books[min];
          books[min] = tempBook;
            }

          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just do `if(bookcmp(&books[i], &books[j]) == 1) { swap books[i] with books[j] }`?   (Still using 3 assignments like your current code).   That gets rid of `min` entirely, vastly simplifying the loop body down to the usual compare-and-swap.

Comment: Peter always coming through with the good advice! In truth, I actually didn't even know about that function.